# Macro posix_c_source

Tags: c, macros, posix

I have the original code that is meant to compile in Windows and Linux using gcc.
It works fine even under cygwin. Now, when I try to compile for iOS

```
echo $OSTYPE
darwin14
```

everything seems fine and a build is successfully obtained. However, when I tried to run the CUI app, a message **Segmentation fault 11** is displayed.

After a couple of days searching on internet, by chance I found this [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html).

As a result, I made the following change in one of the *.c file

```
-#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309
+#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199506
```

and the new build works fine. Although I am not a programmer, I am wondering what would be so significant different between these two macros? Could you comment on why such change becomes so significant.

Comment: When you get a crash such as segmentation fault, your first action should not be to redefine special macros. Instead it should be to *debug* the application, to find the location and the cause of the crash. Just because it *seems* to work, it's not guaranteed that the underlying problem is actually fixed. You might still have the undefined behavior in the code, and the crash (or other unexpected behavior) might come back when you least expect it.

Comment: Is your code multi-threaded? That could explain it because `199506` introduced threads (and without it your C library may not include thread safety constructs). Otherwise, it's hard to tell without looking at any code.

Comment: @Joachim: Thx for your suggestion. I am aware that my approach is not a professional one. Unfortunately, my debugging skills are almost inexistent.

Comment: @P.P. : Thank you for your replay. I have to check more what multi-thread means and if it exists in this context.

Comment: @PP: You were correct.

Answer (score 1):

though it is only 1 line of code,but it may make big difference,POSIX is a standard,it define the interface between OS and applications,and it has many different version(you can think it similar with a hardware USB standard , it has many version, like USB 1.0 and USB 2.0).

sometimes programmer can't determine which platform the program will be work on , it may run on Linux , may run on windows, maybe the system provide old standard interface, maybe a new one.

So , programmer add this kind of macros, write codes for many different interface,for example ,a source code like this:

```
#define WIN
#ifdef WIN
    <part 1:1000 lines of code>
#endif
#ifdef LINUX
    <part 2:1000 lines of code>
#endif 
    <1000 lines that not depend on system , can both run on Linux and Windows.>
```

the compiler will compile part 1(discard part 2), but when you change  **#define WIN** to **#define LINUX** , it will contain part 2(and discard part 1) ! you may think you only changed 1 line , but the compiler may choose or discard thousands of lines (maybe even more ,maybe less, that depend on the code)